# Onload Page load extern page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i use this AJAX script to load an extern page (mpt_planningen_overzicht.php) into a div op the mainpage (mainpage.php) when people select or unselect a checkbox.

But i also want to load the data from the extern page in the div when mainpage.php is opened.

How can i do this?

Script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(){
         var formData = $(":input,:hidden").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mpt_planningen_overzicht.update.php",
        data: formData,
    success: function(result){ /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
      $("#resultaat").html(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV */            

    }

    });
});
});
</script>
```

I thought something like this:

```
function onLoadSubmit() {
    document.nameofForm.submit();
}
```

But the Ajax script that checks if a selectbox is checked/unchecked is already on mainpage.php, so when i add the script above, it will continue reloading.

Comment: Put the AJAX login in to its own function, then call that function in document.ready and in the checkbox's event handler. Also note that when dealing with checkboxes you should use the `change` event, not `click`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//separationg the function that loads the page in order to use it multiple times
var loadSepratePage = function(){ 
    var formData = $(":input,:hidden").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mpt_planningen_overzicht.update.php",
        data: formData,
        success: function(result){ /* GET THE TO BE RETURNED DATA */
          $("#resultaat").html(result); /* THE RETURNED DATA WILL BE SHOWN IN THIS DIV */            
        }

    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', loadSepratePage); // without paranthesis () to pass the function as a parameter

    loadSepratePage() // with paranthesis () to actually call the function

});
</script>
```

If this is not what you mean feel free to leave  comment